# Rails how to detect if a partial was inserted using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I detect if a partial is currently displaying while in javascript?

So using semi pseudo-code and trying to be as simplistic as possible to get my intent across,

In my controller I have:

```
def index
    if (request.xhr?)//coming from pagination ajax request
        @sessions = Session.paginate(.......)
        if @sessions.empty?
            render: partial => 'nomoresessions'
        else
            render: partial => 'sessions'
        end
    else//standard request to display
        @sessions = Session.paginate(.....)
    end

end
```

In my javascript:

```
function doCheck(){
  var canContinuePaginating = true;
  if (nomoresessions partial was inserted){//<--- This is what I need to figure out
      canContinuePaginating = false;
  }
  if (canContinuePaginating){
      //do stuff
  }  

}
```

In case anyone is wondering why I need this, I am appending rows to the bottom of a table via a partial and using pagination as the user scrolls and once I have reached the bottom I want to append some kind of visual indicator to indicate we are at the bottom of the list via a nomoresesssions partial. Then, if the user keeps trying to scroll, I would like to detect via javascript that the nomoresesssions partial is currently displaying and therefore don't attempt to paginate anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The one easy way that I could think of is that you might want to add some class or id to your 'nomoresessions' partial, something like

```
<li class="end-of-list">
  <img src="end.png" />
</li>
```

Then in your `doCheck` you can do:

```
function doCheck(){
  var canContinuePaginating = true;
  if ($('ul.content .end-of-list').length) {
    canContinuePaginating = false;
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Not sure why. The partial is being inserted and displayed. I keep getting $('ul.content .end-of-list').length = 0